# Early examples of proof appraisals

Tags: soft-question, ho.history-overview

What are the earliest known examples for attributing proofs as 'deep', 'elegant' or 'beautiful' (or their equivalents in other languages)?

Gauß for example called one of his results 'remarkable' [Theorema Egregium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theorema_Egregium) -- are there earlier examples of such proof-attributes?

I thought of this when I saw the article [Beauty Is Not Simplicity: An Analysis of Mathematicians' Proof Appraisals](https://academic.oup.com/philmat/article/23/1/87/1432455).

Comment: @Matt: thanks for being faster with editing the question than I was.

Comment: The Gauss example was not his calling his *proof* remarkable (elegant, etc.) but rather calling the phenomenon itself, an objective "fact of nature" as it were,  remarkable.

Answer (score 4):

Probably, one of the earliest examples is the famous appraisal made by [Plutarch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plutarch) (c. AD 46 – c. 120) about Archimedes geometric work. The [translation in English](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&ei=ab5CXra9HZqAhbIPk-6d6AU&q=Plutarch%20Archimedes%20investigation&oq=Plutarch%20Archimedes%20investigation&gs_l=psy-ab.3..33i160.36017.38333..38611...0.0..0.148.1996.0j16......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i19j0i22i30i19j0i22i30j33i21.YDw5Tf4fH40&ved=0ahUKEwj2ldTv3snnAhUaQEEAHRN3B10Q4dUDCAo&uact=5#) is as follows:

> It is not possible to find in all
>   geometry more difficult and intricate questions, or more simple and lucid explanations. Some ascribe
>   this to his natural genius; while others think that incredible effort and toil produced these, to all
>   appearances, easy and unlaboured results. No amount of investigation of yours would succeed in
>   attaining the proof, and yet, once seen, you immediately believe you would have discovered it; by so
>   smooth and so rapid a path he leads you to the conclusion required [...] His discoveries were numerous and admirable; but he is
>   said to have requested his friends and relations that, when he was dead, they would place over his tomb
>   a sphere containing a cylinder, inscribing it with the ratio which the containing solid bears to the
>   contained.

Answer (score 2):

An early example is [Proclus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proclus)'s Commentary on the First Book of Euclid, though "early" still means roughly 750 years after Euclid. This has been translated into English, and you can see a sample [here](https://www.maths.tcd.ie/~dwilkins/Courses/ET7246/LocalResources2018/Proclus__CommentaryOnEuclid__ChapIV__TranslatedTTaylor.html): "He reduced to invincible demonstrations, such things as were exhibited by others with a weaker arm."

Comment: I'm saving that for when I need a really strong referee report (or reference letter, maybe).